# How to show count items in cart in header Open Cart?

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I need to show count of items in cart in Header.

I tried to edit `header.php` file as:

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
$data['total'] = count($products);
```

And after to display this in template `header.tpl`:

```
<?php echo $total?>
```

Comment: Your code is correct and worked for me.

Comment: Please refresh modification cache from admin after your changes & then check it. Please Go to admin > Extensions > Modifications and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner) for update the system & then check it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but you can also use command `$this->cart->countProducts()`